# Opening CSV IOError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied

Tags: python, csv

I have this in my python script:

```
import csv
file = open('test.csv', 'a')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.csv'
```

I've tried opening it like this as well and I get the same error.

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as result
```

I've also tried recreating the csv file but nothing seems to work. The file is in the same folder as the script so the path shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Did you checked your `test.csv` permission's file ?

Comment: How do I do that? And what am I looking for?

Comment: if you're using any `Gnu/Linux` or `OSX` or `BSD` OS, open a terminal then go to the directory of your `test.csv` file then do: `ls -l` then check the permissions of your `test.csv` file if you have the right to read it and/or write into it.

Comment: The file is probably being used by another app, or even another script you left running., also check if you have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: -rw-r--r--  is what I got for the permission of the file

Comment: Permission _**-rw-r--r--**_ means the owner of the file has read/write Permission. Are you the Owner of the file?

Answer (score 5):

The file may be open somewhere in your machine. Close the file and rerun your script. If you can't find the file, try renaming your file in the script to something different, say, test1.csv.

That way you temporarily just test if the test.csv file being open is actually the problem.